# How to create a diagonal within a nested for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, diagonal

Ok, so I have to create something that looks like this:

Enter dimension of board: 8

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

My problem is that my code will only create a rectangle of 0s and I'm not sure how to add the diagonal of 1s.

My code so far:

```
dimension=int(input('Enter dimension of triangle: '))

if dimension < 2:

    print('Invalid input')

else:

    for r in range(dimension):

        for c in range(dimension):

            print("0",end=" ")

        print()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> dimension = 8
>>> for r in range(dimension):
...     for c in range(dimension):
...          print(int(c==r), end=" ")
...     print()
... 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

For the general case, you can put the alternatives in the `print` function like this

```
     print("1" if c==r else "0", end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the diagonal, the row index is equal to the column index, so you can do:

```
dimension=int(input('Enter dimension of triangle: '))

if dimension < 2:
    print('Invalid input')

else:
    for r in range(dimension):
        for c in range(dimension):
            # If we are on the diagonal
            if r == c:
                num = "1"
            # Otherwise
            else:
                num = "0"

            print(num, end=" ")

        print()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = np.zeros((8, 8), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, 1)
```

then if you want to print it

```
s = StringIO()
np.savetxt(s,a,fmt="%d")
print s.getvalue()
```